# I had angularjs application. How to convert this into mobile app

Tags: angularjs, mobile

I had web application written in AngularJS which works in all desktop and mobile browsers like Chrome, Safari etc.

Is there a way to convert it into mobile app?

Comment: I believe Ionic would do that

Answer (score 1):

You can use the framework Ionic coupled with cordova

http://ionicframework.com/
https://cordova.apache.org/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova can do the job. As you have already an app, just need to build it using cordova. If you want to start a new project from scratch, Ionic will be a great option. As it is providing the layout and mobile friendly components for our use.

Please follow the steps in : https://cordova.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use phone gap. In phone gap there is also plugins available for the mobile phone events like shaking and etc.
With the free version you can not add plugins, you have to buy phone gap for that.

Just create package with pure HTML, CSS and java script (angular js) and build it on the phone gap then you can download sdk and then you can install it on android.
[Phone Gap](https://build.phonegap.com/)